# Text font styles not reaching Amplify from Figma

Tags: aws-amplify, figma

I am using Amplify to develop React screens and trying to use Figma to develop the screens which then can be imported to Amplify and then to the local development environment.

Creating some simple forms in Figma with labels, text fields, and buttons.

Then choosing some colors for the buttons and formatting the labels to have some specific colors, shadow effects, etc.

Then I import the screens into Amplify from Figma using the Figma URL of the components library.

The button styles (colors) are reaching Amplify but the label's styles (color, shadow effects) are lost. Labels are plain.

Any suggestions?